# How Lambda Expression works

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

in an interview , interviewer ask me following query

```
int[] array = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
Func<int, int> func = i =>
{
    Console.Write(array[i]);
    return i;
};

var result = array.Where(e => e <= func(2)).ToArray();
```

so will any one guide me how `e <= func(2)` thing works?
and how last line i.e

```
var result = array.Where(e => e <= func(2)).ToArray();
```

works?

Comment: Research `Closures`, or possibly `Predicates`, depending on where your confusion lies.

Comment: Where exactly does your confusion lie? What don't you understand?

Comment: I think the interviewer was trying to trick you with two arrows.

Comment: i am confusing over "<=" sign...because it is like what we use in Lamdba(=>)...is this sign use in Lambda ?? or it is just for creating confusion??

Comment: Confusion = true. Nothing to do with the lambda, just a plain old less than or equals

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be easier to understand if you use parentheses:

```
var result = array.Where(e => (e <= func(2))).ToArray();
```

This

```
e => ...
```

Constructs a function which takes one argument.

This

```
e <= func(2)
```

compares `e` to `func(2)`. `func(2)` calls the function `func` with the argument `2`.

All in all, the `<=` has nothing to do with `=>`. They are two completely different operators. To summarize `... => ...` constructs a function. `... <= ...` compares the arguments.

Comment: In other words, `=>` is a bad approximation of “⇒” and `<=` is a worse approximation of “≤”.

Answer (score 4):

`Func<int, int>` means that `func` is a function with one parameter of type int and result of type int. The `i` is the parameter. The function writes array element to console and returns the parameter unmodified.

The `Where` function returns all cases that match the given predicate, `ToArray` makes an array from IEnumerable returned by `Where` (read about linq). `e => e <= func(2)` is a function with one parameter of type int (the same as the collection type), and with result of type bool. You can write it as a normal function:

```
bool Foo(int e) {
    return e <= func(2);
}
```

And since `func` returns an unmodified parameter, it's functionally equals to

```
bool Foo(int e) {
    return e <= 2;
}
```

but not minding the side effect.

Comment: Excellent anwer. Similar to what I was going to post! :)

Comment: @Dmitry Polyanitsa...will you please tell me that in Func <int, int> , which parameter is for return?and which one is  for input?

Comment: The first for input, the second for result: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the possible combinations of `=` and `<` or `>` in C#:

- `<=` is the "less than or equal" operator
- `>=` is the "greater than or equal" operator
- `=>` is the lambda operator, on the left are the parameters of the lambda, on the right is the body
- `=<` is not valid, there is no such operator

Answer (score 2):

It means for all `e` where `e` is smaller or equal then func(2). The `ToArray()` call results in an evaluation of the LINQ expression, so `3333333333` is printed on Console

Comment: `23` gets printed? I would have guessed `3333333333`

Comment: The func(2) always displays the third element of the array (3) and is evaluated for every element in the array, hence, it displays 3333333333

Comment: To me it seems that result 1,2,3  will be, considering that the argument is 2.

Comment: func(2) will be evaluated for every element in the array. It spits out arr[2], which is 3, then returns 2

Comment: +1 but, 1,2 will be output array, and just 3333333333 will be written in output

Answer (score 1):

`Where()` is a [LINQ query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) that filters an array based on a test contained in its lambda expression parameter.

`e => e <= func(2)`, is a lambda expression which is passed to the `Where()` query to take every element in `array` and add that element to `result` if the value is less than or equal to ("**<=**") func(2).

`ToArray()` is a conversion operator which acts like a cast from IEnumerable to array.

For more on LINQ see [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).